# Excel: Calculation with different beginning dates

Tags: excel-formula

I have a long time-series of monthly returns for the S&P500. I would like to calculate the 3-month return, for a subset of dates?

For example, I would like to calculate the 3-month return for the following

```
 A     B     C
Month  Year  3-Month Return    
Jan   1929
Dec   1948
July  1981
```

I have monthly return data like:

```
A        B       C
Month  Year   Monthly Return
Jan    1929   0.102
Feb    1929   0.072
Mar    1929   -0.231
....
....
Dec   2019    0.157
```

So the first calculation would be something like (1+0.102)*(1+0.072)*(1-0.231)-1. I can do this manually but have many calculations, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you explain better ? Do you want summary of Jan, Feb March and next Feb, March, Apr, ... or what is the calculation suppose to result in?

Comment: use match to find the corresponding index then use index formula to get the values. for Dec 1948, you'd need to do `(1+dec1948)(1+jan1949)(1+feb1949)-1`, is that correct?

Comment: @Atreyagaurav thanks. Yep that is correct. Do you know if there a way to do this for many different start dates (e.g. Jan 1929, Dec 1948, July 1981 etc etc) without having to type them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find the match, you need a unique column, so combine A & B to another column, so that the month+year combination is unique, then use that combination to find the values.
Suppose you have data in this form:

[image]

The formula for match index is `=match(P3,U$3:U$13,0)` and that for your 3 monthly return is `=(1+index(V$3:V$13,Q3))*(1+index(V$3:V$13,Q3+1))*(1+index(V$3:V$13,Q3+2))-1`

You can put the match index inside the formula in C column to avoid the column, but you'd have to put it 3 times. you can also use different combination for combined date, like the actual date format of mm/yyyy, it'll still work.

Comment: N/A for dec 1948 because I was too lazy to simulate the whole data, should work on yours.